# Matching a Value from XSLT Variable

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to test to see whether a value of tag matches my variables. My input XML might look something:

```
<root>
    <userid>user1<userid>
    <performance>
      <doOne>

      </doOne>
    </performance>
</root>
```

I have created a global variable with a comma delimited list of `userId`'s, and I need to check whether this user can perform `doOne`, i.e.

```
<xsl:variable name="performerable">
    <perform name="doOne" users="user3, user6, user1"/>
    <perform name="doTwo" users="user7, user2, user6"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

However, when I check whether the user exists in any of the `perform`, I get an error with the following setup:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="contains($performerable/perform[name='doOne'].users, 'user6')">
        <accepted>
    </xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
```

And running it through Eclipse XSL tranformation, I get the following:

```
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Expected ,, but found: .users
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct XPath expression to extract the `users` attribute from the `perform` element that has name `doOne` would be

```
$performerable/perform[@name='doOne']/@users
```

but this will only work in XSLT 2.0 - in 1.0 (which is what `javax.xml.transform` uses unless you have specifically included Saxon 9 in your project) you can't use XPaths to look inside variables that are defined with content, only variables defined with a `select` expression.  The value of a variable with content is something called a ["result tree fragment"](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Result-Tree-Fragments) which is something you can take the `value-of` or `copy-of` but not something you can look inside using XPath like you could if it were a proper node set.

When you have a completely static piece of data like this there is a trick you can do with the `document` function to treat the stylesheet itself as another input XML document, which lets you access the relevant bits as a node set rather than a fragment:

```
<xsl:variable name="performerableRtf">
  <perform name="doOne" users="user3, user6, user1"/>
  <perform name="doTwo" users="user7, user2, user6"/>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="performerable" select="document('')//xsl:variable[@name='performerableRtf']"/>
```

But I would recommend you change your XML representation slightly - if you use separate elements for each id rather than a comma separated list:

```
<xsl:variable name="performerableRtf">
  <perform name="doOne">
    <u>user3</u>
    <u>user6</u>
    <u>user1</u>
  </perform>
  <!-- ... -->
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="performerable" select="document('')//xsl:variable[@name='performerableRtf']"/>
```

Then the test becomes a simple equals:

```
$performerable/perform[@name='doOne']/u = 'user6'
```

since an `=` comparison with a node set on one (or both) of the sides succeeds if *any* node on one side matches *any* node on the other.

Comment: I am using XSLT 1.0. So how can I accomplish this since `xsl:when` does not have a `select` expression?